# VBoxManage: error: The specified user was not able to logon on guest

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm setting up vm to receive files from a linux host. I can't seem to figure out why I can't logon to the vm guest using vboxmanage. I've included details about the vm and the error below.

**The error:**

```
$ /usr/bin/vboxmanage guestcontrol hybrid-analysis exec --username hybridanalysis --password hybrid --verbose
Opening guest session as user 'hybridanalysis' ...
Waiting for guest session to start ...
VBoxManage: error: The specified user was not able to logon on guest
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component GuestSession, interface IGuestSession, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "WaitForArray(ComSafeArrayAsInParam(aSessionWaitFlags), 30 * 1000, &sessionWaitResult)" at line 998 of file VBoxManageGuestCtrl.cpp
Closing guest session ...
```

**About the VM:**

OS: Windows 7 (64 bit) and 
Guest Additions is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by completely rebuilding the vm and reinstalling the os. I'm not sure what the original issue was but rebuilding everything resolved it.

Answer (score 22):

Try this: in "***Run***" type "*gpedit.msc*". 
There, go to [Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only] and set it to DISABLED.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!